# CouchDB returns "does not eval to a function"

Tags: couchdb

I got this code

```
 {
    "_id": "_design/test",
    "_rev": "10-651aa6314effdad0bca00fc4a3da38f6",
    "views": {
       "foo": {
           "map": "(function(doc){ emit(doc._id, doc._rev)})"
       },
       "bar": {
           "map": "(function(doc){if(doc.date && doc.title) {emit(doc.date, doc.title);})"
       }
      }
    }
```

Why does it return an:

> Expression does not eval to a function. ((new String("(function(doc){if(doc.date && doc.title) {emit(doc.date, doc.title);})")))

Comment: It's probably looking for `function` at the very beginning of the string. Try removing the parenthesis around your function.

Comment: You're also missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: Removing or adding parenthesis isn't the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old and the answer is actually in the comments of the question, but it seems like there should be a posted answer.

The final curly brace of the function is missing. Indented, it looks like the following:

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.date && doc.title) {
    emit(doc.date, doc.title);
  }
}
```

Notice the two braces at the end in the one line version:

```
function(doc){if(doc.date && doc.title){emit(doc.date, doc.title);}}
```

I prefer to indent and uses spaces, so I don't miss those things.